# How to require only one of the props in React with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm creating typings for an NPM module [Informed](https://joepuzzo.github.io/informed/?selectedKind=Form&selectedStory=Props&full=0&addons=0&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=REACT_STORYBOOK%2Freadme%2Fpanel). If you follow the link, you'll see that the `Form` component requires either `children` or `render` or `component` prop. Here's how I attempted to solve it with TS:

```js
export type ChildFunction<C> = (props: C) => React.ReactNode;

export interface BasicFormProps {
  // form props...
}

export interface ChildrenFormProps extends BasicFormProps {
  children:
    | React.ReactNode
    | ChildFunction<FormContext>;
}

export interface ComponentFormProps extends BasicFormProps {
  component: React.ComponentType<FormContext>;
}

export interface RenderFormProps extends BasicFormProps {
  render: ChildFunction<FormContext>;
}

export type FormProps = ChildrenFormProps | ComponentFormProps | RenderFormProps;
```

It does error, if I try to call the component without any props, saying that `render` prop is required. However, the error often persists even if I provide an alternate required prop (`children` or `component`). besides, it doesn't look like the most eloquent method...

Answer (score -2):

You can use oneOfType from React PropTypes. I think that would work with problem.

Check it out here: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes

You can moreover use like below:

```
PropTypes.oneOfType([ 
  PropTypes.instanceOf(ChildrenFormProps),
  PropTypes.instanceOf(ComponentFormProps),
  PropTypes.instanceOf(RenderFormProps)
]);
```

Comment: Well, I'm looking for something exactly like that, but in Typescript...

Comment: It would work with Typescript as well.! As Classes mentioned in instanceOf is Typescript class.